# Can someone explain the proper way to sub class a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios4

Can some explain how to properly subclass a UIViewController and then load it into the window without using a nib.

Do i need to set the view and when do I do it? loadView?

My app crashes  when I use my customUIViewController sub-class.  Everything loads up find until I click a button and it compains about "Bad Access"

```
GettingStarted *vc = [[GettingStarted alloc] init];


UISplitViewController *split = self.splitViewController;
NSArray *vcArray = split.viewControllers;

NSLog(@"viewcontroll cout:%d", vcArray.count);

    // this line of code crashes my app. I fi comment it out everything works fine
UINavigationController *detailViewController = (UINavigationController*)[vcArray objectAtIndex:1];
//


detailViewController  pushViewController:vc animated:YES];


[vc release];
```

GettingStarted.m

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];

//UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] init];

[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Getting Started"];

UIImageView *noUsersIV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_users.png"]];

[noUsersIV setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 466, 961.0f)];
[noUsersIV setHidden:NO];
[noUsersIV setTag:1006];
[[self view] addSubview:noUsersIV];
[noUsersIV release];


UIButton *btnAddUser = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnAddUser setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_users_button_standard.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnAddUser setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_users_button_activated.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btnAddUser addTarget:self action:@selector(addUser:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnAddUser setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 428,466, 124)];


[[self view] addSubview:btnAddUser];

[btnAddUser release];


//self.view = baseView;

//[baseView release];

}
```

Comment: It's complaining about "bad access" because you screwed up your memory management somewhere. Take a look at the backtrace in GDB to see where the crash is happening. That'll give you a strong clue as to what object you forgot to retain/overreleased.

Comment: Way too little detail. If you can see the view and buttons then you are probably creating things in the right place (loadView), but have a bad retain count on an object. Post your loadView code.

Comment: updated the post. If I comment out the line where I do grab the UINavigationController then everything works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the result of your log message? Are you sure you have >=2 objects in that array?

Does the crash happen with pushNavigationController on the callstack, or does the crash happen later?

You also don't need to release split, vcArray, or detailViewController. The [detailViewController release] will certainly cause a crash. The others would cause crashes later.

When functions return objects unless you are calling retain on it, **or the function returning the object is named alloc/copy/create**, the object will be autoreleased so you **don't need to release it.**

```
someArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]; // no need to release
someArray = someClass.array; // no need to release

someArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // alloc, need to release
someArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...] retain]; // retained, need to release
```

The reason you would call retain in the second example above is if you wish to use the object outside of this function. If you do you need to retain it, if not it will be auto-released later.

Update: You have a similar problem where you are adding the button.

Comment: OK I updated the post to reflect my code and I still have a problem (same)

Comment: You see anything strange in my GettingStart viewDidLoad?  It is a sub class of UIViewController

Comment: Yes - read what I wrote above regarding when to release, and compare it to how you are constructing the button

Comment: I dont see what you talking about. Am I not suppose to release them?

Comment: I have bolded the relevant passage. Pay attention to what you are doing with the UIButton at the bottom of loadView. I don't mean to be vague, but understanding what is wrong here is fundamental to Objective-C so if it takes you a day to figure out, it will be a day well spent.

Answer (score 1):

get rid of this line of code

```
[btnAddUser release];
```

This object 'btnAddUser' is part of the autorelease pool, you must not call release. You only have to `release/autorelease` objects created or assigned using

```
alloc, copy, or retain
```